# Set inheritedByDefault to false in plugin.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, plugins

I'm having trouble while developping a maven plugin to find out how to configure the inheritedByDefault property to be set to false in the generated plugin.xml file.

Be careful, I don"t speak about the inheritedByDefault property of each mojo, but the general inheritedByDefault property at the root of the *plugin*  tag.

[Plugin descriptor documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/descriptor-mojo.html) isn't very loquacious about this subject and I can't find anything on Internet.

Comment: Can you show your code ? What exactly is the problem ? Just setting it to a particular value ? Just use the appropriate value of the annotation (http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html) ?

Comment: I'm not talking about the mojo declaration, but the plugin configuration himself. The [plugin descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-plugin-api/plugin.html) has a *inheritedByDefault* property at the root of the *plugin* tag that I can't find how to set.

Setting it to false seems to be the only solution to always prevent plugin to be executed with each pom compilation on a multi-module project.

Comment: This is [described in the plugin configuration guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_inherited_Tag_In_Build_Pluginshttp://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_inherited_Tag_In_Build_Plugins) which means to inherit the configuration from the parent or not.  Can you describe more in detail what you like to achieve?